Migrating Customized Dashboards from Grafana to a more recent version
I am currently migrating the customized Grafana dashboards from version 7.3.1 to version 10.1. The issue is that when I try to migrate the dashboards using JSON I have to "customize" the dashboards again. For instance, when I use JSON I have to customize all the dashboards colors again, and that is a lot of work to do manually. Is there any way I can migrate dashboards with a high customization level without having to redo most of the customization again? I've tried using JSON to migrate the dashboards as I thought they would be just the same as they were in the past version, but all of the customization was gone.
